# `l3build` - How does regression analysis work?

Tags: l3build

Has anyone analysed the `l3build` source code as I am looking for the files to validate, or reject, the output produced by a test file?

Does "everything" is coded in [`l3build-check.lua`](https://github.com/latex3/l3build/blob/main/l3build-check.lua)?

Comment: My question has been edited...

Comment: it is still rather unclear. _you_ have to check the initial saved log (as made by `l3build save`  then a future run of `l3build check` will warn you if something has changed

Comment: You have answered my question. Maybe I should have asked my question on github, but I didn't want to pollute the github repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*you* have to check the initial saved log (as made by `l3build save`)  then a future run of `l3build check` will warn you if something has changed.

l3build does some normalisation of the logs, removing dates, local file paths, line numbers etc, so that you get fewer spurious differences, but the basic model is that output is checked against a human-checked saved output for each test, there is no specific format or intrinsic self-validation of a test result.

Comment: The main lines of code seems to be here : https://github.com/latex3/l3build/blob/main/l3build-check.lua#L104 .

Comment: @projetmbc yes `normalize_log` and the following function with more agressive normalisation for luatex.